# Html.BeginForm and Kendo Ui in MVC 4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, html.beginform

So what I have is a form created with the `beginform` extension like this

```
using (Html.BeginForm("SendEmail", "Email", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "emailForm",    
onsubmit = "return Check();"})){
```

inside I created some Kendo Ui widget like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Senders)</td>
    <td>
      @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name("Sender")
        .DataTextField("Text")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .BindTo(Model.Senders))
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>@Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(@Model.RecipientTable))</td>                                    
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td colspan ="2">
       @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
         .Name("Users")
         .DataTextField("Name")
         .DataValueField("Id")
         .Placeholder("Optional - Choose additional users to send emails to:")
         .ItemTemplate("#=LastName #, #=FirstName # #=MiddleInitial #")
         .TagTemplate("#=LastName #, #=FirstName # #=MiddleInitial #")
         .BindTo(Model.OptionalUsers))
     </td>
  </tr>
```

in my controller Email I have this method

```
[HttpPost]
public bool SendEmail(EmailModel Email){ .. stuff....}
```

Where the `EmailModel` is tightly bind to the view that contains the form from above. The question and trouble I am having is that is it possible and if so how, to have the model passed to the method containing information about what the user chose? Or is it that I can not use the form's submit and will have to manually get the value and pass it as a JSON to the controller via custom function that does a ajax call?

Comment: if you don't use post then you will need to use an ajax call

Comment: @MattBodily What do you mean? Am I not using post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I read that you weren't using post.  The only items that are returned automatically through the post are fields that have been put in a for helper.  What we do is

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Sender, new { @class = "ddlSender" })
```

then in the script we initialize the kendo part of it

```
$('.ddlSender').kendoDropDownList();
```

this way the model item is put in a for helper so it gets posted back to the controller and you get the benefits of the kendo dropdown.  Hope this helps

Comment: Ok so it not necessarily the model that is passed back but the value created from the helper. And I guess I can't use the MVC wrapper in this case.

Comment: right,  if you can't use a for helper I would recommend going the ajax route to manually send the values back to the controller